# Apply CSS property only if it overrides, else, do nothing

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to only apply a CSS style if it overrides another? In the case that it does not override, it should not apply itself.

```
<svg ... />
<svg fill="#fff" ... />
```

How would you go about only modifying the fill property if it is defined? Is this possible through only CSS?
Thanks

I have tried using !important to override the property in case it is in-line but I am unable to get the property to apply conditionally.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Oh that's lovely @SolomonUcko, thank you. I don't have much experience with CSS beyond basic styling, and this is spot on :). Cheers. I can mark as answer if you convert it to a response.

Comment: Great, yay! I've posted it as an answer, including some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), and perhaps also [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) to get what the value is:

```
svg[fill] {
    fill: attr(fill);
}
```